Why are the object diffrent in if clauses in Python?
Consider this code:
def dayPress(self, number):
    var = TimeInput()
    if number == 0:
        print(var)
    elif number == 1:
        print(var)

TimeInput is a Kivy object, but that does not matter in this case.
The function dayPressis getting called twice. Once with the number 0, then with the number 1.
The output is the following:
First(with number 0): <main.TimeInput object at 0x0000026E36261000>
Second(with number 1):<main.TimeInput object at 0x0000026E360A13F0>
If you look at the memory location of both objects, you can see that those are diffrent objects. That is not what I want. I want to refer to the same object in both cases.
Why am I refering to diffrent objects and how can I change that?
Is it because I am calling the function twice and I am creating var twice?
Thanks



Is it because I am calling the function twice and I am creating var twice?


Yes.

Yes,Each time the function is called, it creates a new memory space on the stack for the variable var. Not only twice but if you run it again with for 0 you'll see different memory location.

Perhaps you want to treat var more like number and pass them both into your method

Every time you execute TimeInput() you are creating a new TimeInput object .

As an alternative to @JonSG's answer, you could use a global variable if  var needs to be accessed from many locations in your program without mutating it. If you want thread safety, you can wrap var in a mutex lock. The use of global variables is discouraged in most cases, though.
